# How to create a type helper that uses information about an object to infer a new type

Tags: typescript

There is a `typeof` method for generating a type from a value, but it only converts the value directly into a type.
I want to use the value of one object to create type information for another object, as followings,

```js
type Column = Readonly<{ type: "numeric" | "text"; name: string }>;

type TypeOfColumns<T extends Column[]> = {}; // ...

const columns: Column[] = [
    { type: "numeric", name: "id" },
    { type: "text", name: "firstName" },
];

// If I wrote the following,
type ColumnType = TypeOfColumns<typeof columns>;

// I want the type to be inferred as follows,
type NeedColumnType = { id: number; firstName: string };
```

I thought I could do it by using extends to read the values, but it did not work at all.

```js
type Column = Readonly<{ type: "numeric" | "text"; name: string }>;

type TypeOfColumn<T extends Column> = {
    [key in T["name"]]: T["type"] extends "numeric" ? number : string;
};

type TypeOfColumns<T extends Column[]> = {
    [key in T[number]["name"]]: TypeOfColumn<T[number]>;
};

const columns: Column[] = [
    { type: "numeric", name: "id" },
    { type: "text", name: "firstName" },
];

type ColumnType = TypeOfColumn<typeof columns[0]>;
/* Output

    type ColumnType = {
        [x: string]: string;
    }
*/

type ColumnsType = TypeOfColumns<typeof columns>;
/* Output

type ColumnsType = {
    [x: string]: TypeOfColumn<Readonly<{
        type: "numeric" | "text";
        name: string;
    }>>;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with `columns`. The type of columns is currently `Column[]`. Using `typeof` on `column` will therefore evaluate to `Column[]`.

You instead want the compiler to *infer* the literal type by removing the type annotation. This needs to be done with [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) , so that the compiler infers the literal types instead of just `string`. Optionally, you can use [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) `readonly Column[]` to validate the type.

```
const columns = [
    { type: "numeric", name: "id" },
    { type: "text", name: "firstName" },
] as const satisfies readonly Column[]
```

The constraint of `TypeOfColumns` now has to change to accept `readonly` arrays. The mapping logic inside the type was also needs to change. We map over `T[number]` instead of `T[number]["name"]`. Each union member `K` can be used to extract the property name `K["name"]` and the corresponding type `K["type"]`.

```
type TypeOfColumns<T extends readonly Column[]> = {
    [K in T[number] as K["name"]]: K["type"] extends "numeric" 
      ? number 
      : string;
};

type ColumnType = TypeOfColumn<typeof columns[0]>;
/*
    type ColumnType = {
        id: number;
    }
*/

type ColumnsType = TypeOfColumns<typeof columns>;
/*
    type ColumnsType = {
        id: number;
        firstName: string;
    }
*/
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UBKECGAJnGgiADwDeUokAXFAERqoQBOAlgMaNQA+TYBAAewRgG4oafCggMAzsE5oA5lAC+APnEAoHbWgAVcBADyAM3jJ05Q1BFC0hebESo0mrFEo6ofqADaANYQIFAcGIYBzDIQjAC68QxRjAYJ9qIQTi7MrJw8UAD8UqgARuxQCkoRKrrquvomUMaQFlbu8rYZjs5QbATEpGHt6AHxntg+-oEA0uGRASwo5WzxUPguM9HSsglJUFupJukOWb25svm8xUsrlVCKyrU69XpcJIpQ79ZoLtgBvn81AMDAu7G4jAANFJYqCOIReOpIYC-MCTKChKIoTDZKDzBw2IoAHKxRHItYbL4fYAPfDADjyfEQFz9IgkMiuH5jPQGTnuFrQbACtpuGwGODmKk-eQBAAM410AHoAFRQUxIYBgDUomhNEZoAVeKbTfzwhi3di6abqHTKxU8vWi36GoUmEXS8jiyXfDraHQqnW8-XyF3eHXTM0lZaW8P+fGE4Ak3EPaqqK3+G12oA)

Comment: Thank!!! 
Exactly what I was looking for!
I had seen the `satisfies` Operator before, but this is how you use it! 
By the way, I asked this question because I thought this derivation could be done somehow, but can it be done in the opposite direction?My sense is that is impossible.

Comment: About the opposite direction: Do you mean from `ColumnsType` to the `columns` value? That would not be possible since you can't convert types to runtime values. Or do you mean from `ColumnsType` to the *type* of `columns`? This would not be impossible but also not something you would want to do. The properties in `ColumnsType` are unordered so converting it to an ordered tuple type is not easy nor reliable.